# React PropTypes.any attributes

Tags: reactjs, attributes, children

I want to get size attribute of my props.image

this is my code of props -->

```
    FormImageCustom.propTypes = {
  image: React.PropTypes.any,
};
```

the console log where I check what's inside -->

```
{console.log('ruta2', props.image)}
```

the result in console -->

[image]

what i have tried -->

```
this.props.image[1].props.children
```

something like this -->

```
 const  childrenPropTypeLogic = (props, image, size) => {
          const prop = props[image];
          return React.Children
                   .toArray(prop)
                   .find(child => child.type !== 'div');
 };
```

How can I get size property?

Comment: From the log screenshot, I think you can simply access `size` via `props.image.size`. Is that what you want ?

Comment: omg, I was using more complicated code and didn't try simple way. Thank's!!